# Adding images to a Bootstrap Carousel with AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Carousel like this:

```
 <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-block">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

                        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" id="carrusel">
                            <div class="carousel-item item active">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="mysource.jpg" alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="mysource.jpg" alt="Second slide">
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item item">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="mysource.jpg" alt="Third slide">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This works fine. Everything works.

I want to load images with Javascript, so I did this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        url: '/getmoreimages/' + someid,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data.imageurl, function (key,data) {
                $('#carrusel').append($('<div class="carousel-item item active"><img class="d-block img-fluid" src='  + data + '></div>'));
            });

            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
```

I was expecting that the carousel would add more images depending on where you click.

Instead, it adds an static carousel that doesn't work at all for each image, breaking the page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the `active` class from the divs you're inserting

Comment: try fixing your loop if data is an array, something like: `$.each(data, function(key, element) { ...img-fluid" src='  + element.imageurl + '>...  })`

Comment: did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: @Karlos Still not solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If data is an array with objects like:

```
{ ...,
  imageurl: String,
  ... 
}
```

Then try to modify your loop as follows:

```
success: function (data) {
   $.each(data, function (key, elem) {
      $('#carrusel').append($('<div class="carousel-item item active"><img class="d-block img-fluid" src='  + elem.imageurl + '></div>'));
   });

   //create carousel instance
}
```

Have in mind than the js carrousel loader might need the images to be already present in the html to render properly.

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that your "data.imageurl" in $.each is an array and gives correct url, then try below for your AJAX' success function

```
success: function (data){

    $.each(data.imageurl, function (key,data) {
        $('#carrusel').append($('<div class="carousel-item item"><img class="d-block img-fluid" src='  + data + '></div>'));
    });

    $('.carousel').carousel();

}
```

Comment: @prgrm
Can you please add a jsFiidle file?